# Error-Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question first of all. Im having trouble with this error message in the title via Brackets.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(theForm) {
    "use strict";
    /*global alert*/
    var formValid = true,
        elementCount = 0;
    while (elementCount <= theForm.length) {
        if (theForm.elements[elementCount].type === "text") {
            if (theForm.elements[elementCount].value() === "") {
                alert("Please complete all the form elements");
                theForm.elements[elementCount].focus;
                formValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return formValid;
    }

} </script>
```

The error comes in the line  "theForm.elements[elementCount].focus;"

Any guidance or help is much appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focus` is a function. accessing it, but not using it for anything has no effect, so that statement isn't doing anything. You probably meant to call it like this;

```
theForm.elements[elementCount].focus();
```

Comment: You are correct, thank you! So being as new as I am to this, I need to end my loop. What would be a proper statement to end it? My last error I'm throwing is "Strange Loop"

Comment: @rworthy7 you are not incrementing `elementCount` so you're testing the same element on each iteration of your loop. You should add `elementCount++` to the end of your loop, or, better yet, use a for loop.

Comment: and don't return that the form is valid until after the whole loop finishes. Right now you're either exiting the loop after one interaction or returning from the whole function you never return (so undefined will be returned) if you reach the `break;` statement and the `return statement can only be reached when `formValid = true;`

Comment: Please excuse my novice level here. On the line following the formValid=true, you are suggesting to add a for line.
    for (elementCount++);